# Spawning a terminal other than cmd.exe with git bash

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, git-bash

I am using Windows 7, which has GIT installed on it.
I have a bash script that I created to do some decryption for me.  When I open a git bash terminal and run it, it runs fine.  This script requires input from the user (potentially).  It prompts the user for a string and then attempts to decrypt it.

I want to make an icon on the desktop that I can double-click on it and it will run.  This I did by creating the following bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -i C:\Mybin\mydecrypt
```

This works fine.  The problem is, it still executes in a CMD.EXE.  I do a select and copy of the string (very long and complicated) that I want to decrypt, but when I go to the cmd window there is now way (I can figure out) how to paste it.
I would like to have it open in a different window.

doing *echo $TERM* from the bash window shows "xterm".  So I tried (and did not really believe it would work, which it did not) adding "set TERM=xterm" in the first line of the bat file.  And as I thought, that did not work.  It said the term was XTERM but it was obviously cmd.exe.

I did not find any parameters for bash.exe to specify the terminal type.  I cannot find xterm in my PATH anywhere.  So I am wondering how to do this to get it to open in a terminal type that I can paste text into.  Any ideas?  I do not have admin rights so I cannot install anything.

As a related question, my script uses java, and as you know, Java on windows is
in "/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144" where there is a space between Program and Files (why Microsoft allows spaces in directory names I will never know).  This is not the first java in my path, so I was trying the three following ways, none of which worked:

```
/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -jar c:/MyBin/crypt.jar
"/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" -jar c:/MyBin/crypt.jar
/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144 -jar c:/MyBin/crypt.jar
```

none of which worked.  I finally went to MyBin and did an

```
 ln -s "/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" myjava
```

and then

```
 myjava -jar c:/MyBin/crypt.jar
```

but there should be a way to specify a space in a file name.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can right-click inside the command prompt and select the Paste option.

Comment: If you don't want to open `cmd.exe`, then don't use a `.bat` file, _which is by default opened using `cmd.exe`_. Perhaps you should be using a `.sh` file after having associated its file type with the required shell.

Comment: I did not see any paste option.  I will try using .sh though and see if that helps